# nombre de archivo, concatenado con la fecha del día, ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc, visual-studio-2013

Busco que al subir y al descargar los archivos pdf que subo al servidor, me quede el nombre del archivo + la fecha. mi código es el siguiente:

```
 public FilePathResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        var ruta = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Archivos/"+  fileName + "");
        return File(ruta, "application/pdf");
    }
```

ese es mi código de descarga y para mostrar el nombre del archivo subido ( donde debo concatenar la fecha) es:

```
 facturacion.Archivo = facturacion.PhotoFile.FileName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrias poner:

```
facturacion.Archivo = facturacion.PhotoFile.FileName + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/","");
```

Con esa función tomas la fecha de hoy.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con dentro de la función donde haces `upload` de tu archivo. Ya que es ahí donde guardas el archivo con el nombre.

```
//Obtienes la fecha de hoy
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
//Le entregamos el formato en este caso dd/MM/yyyy
String dateTimeFormat = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
//A la variable fileName le concatenamos la fecha
fileName = fileName + " " + dateTimeFormat;
```

Comment: ¿Cómo? en que método me dices que use esto amigo. gracias por un poco más de orientación.

Comment: Dentro de tu función que sube el archivo ya que ahi es donde queda guardado con el nombre que tu le das.

Comment: Por favor agrega un poco más de información en la respuesta @sioesi (así como la agregaste por medio del comentario), generalmente es una mejor idea acompañar el código de una explicación del mismo, al menos breve.